# Processing append float[]

Tags: processing, utilities

Im working on a Processing App wich is supposed to grap data from a serial port and put in into various graphs. I've downloaded the giCentre Utilities libary to draw the graphs.

Based of one of the examples i got it to plot a simple graph, but since it will be grabbing data from the serial port in real-time i need to be able to add data. Im trying to use the Append() function, but without any luck.

```
import org.gicentre.utils.stat.*;    // For chart classes.


float[] test = {1900, 1910, 1920, 1930, 1940, 1950, 1960, 1970, 1980, 1990};

float[] test2 ={ 19000,  6489,  6401, 7657, 9649, 9767, 12167, 15154, 18200, 23124};

XYChart lineChart;

/** Initialises the sketch, loads data into the chart and customises its appearance.
  */
void setup()
{
  size(500,200);
  smooth();
  noLoop();

  PFont font = createFont("Helvetica",11);
  textFont(font,10);

  // Both x and y data set here.  
  lineChart = new XYChart(this);
  append(test, 2050); 
  append(test2, 21000);
  lineChart.setData(test, test2);

  // Axis formatting and labels.
  lineChart.showXAxis(true); 
  lineChart.showYAxis(true); 
  lineChart.setMinY(0);

  lineChart.setYFormat("###");  
  lineChart.setXFormat("0000");   

  // Symbol colours
  lineChart.setPointColour(color(180,50,50,100));
  lineChart.setPointSize(5);
  lineChart.setLineWidth(2);
}

/** Draws the chart and a title.
  */
void draw()
{
  background(255);
  textSize(9);
  lineChart.draw(15,15,width-30,height-30);

}
```

Isn't the line

```
append(test, 2050); 
append(test2, 21000);
```

supposed to add a new datapoint at (2050, 21000) ? It would be nice to only have to call these every time serial data comes in and then redraw the plot.

Any help or advice is much appreciated.

Comment: Which language is that? Looks like Java, but...

Comment: It's processing, a simple programming language based of Java, see http://processing.org/

Comment: Also check out the Processing [tag info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/processing/info).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `append()` function returns the appended array. `append(test, 2050)` doesn't actually change the `test` array, it *returns* an array equivalent to `test` with 2050 appended to it. So you should be able to do the following:

```
test = append(test, 2050);
test2 = append(test2, 21000);
```

---

**EDIT:**

Here is the documentation on the Processing Reference page: [`append()`](http://processing.org/reference/append_.html). And here is some code which can be run as a simple test (or learning tool):

```
void setup()
{
  int[] a = {1, 2, 3};
  int[] b;
  b = append(a, 4);

  print(a.length + "\n");
  print(b.length);
}
```

which returns

```
3
4
```